# Drop menu with jQuery doesn't work on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying do a simple drop menu to show when mouseover, this script shows another div with the links.

It all works fine but when I try to select one link the other div hides.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#menu_link").mouseover(function() {

        jQuery(".1").show();

    });

  jQuery("#menu_link").mouseout(function() {

        jQuery(".1").hide();

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sx8o1tbh/1/

If you go and put the cursor over the word "Inicio" you see it shows the other div with links but when I try go to this new div it hides, I think something is wrong in the jQuery code.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is something wrong with your CSS, not your JavaScript, put a background color on the #menu_link element and see what the height is for that element, that will send you on the right direction.

Comment: https://cloudup.com/ce9U_IpQJAm look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in JavaScript code. I just changed your css and avoid gap between menu and submenu:

```
#show_links
{
top:35px;
position:absolute;
min-width:10%;
width:auto;
min-height:100px;
height:auto;
border:2px solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sx8o1tbh/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


    $("#menu_link").mouseenter (function () {

        $(".1").show();

    });

    $("#show_links").mouseleave (function () {

        $(".1").hide();

    });

     $("#menu_link").mouseleave (function () {

        $(".1").hide();

    });

});
```

or this can be done the the jquery